# Confusion pointing to lists for values in functions in R

Tags: r

I'm having a problem understanding how R functions interact with variable names. If you pass a variable name into a function, it seems to behave differently than if you pass the variable value to the function, which confuses me.

I have tried searching the forums, but would appreciate some clarification, as I think there is something fundamentally wrong with my understanding of R.

The following code produces the desired effect:

```
library(MASS)

hist(Boston$crim,xlab='Crime Rate',ylab='Frequency', main='Frequency plot of Crime Rate')
```

[Expected Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f8he.png)
The histogram titles and labels are all as defined in the function.

The problem arises, when I try to do it in a loop and do multiple plots, by calling the labels and plots using variables in lists. It seems calling the strings by pointing to a value in a list doesn't pass through to the histogram function.

```
sectors =c('crim','tax','ptratio')
xlabels =c('Crime Rate','Property Tax Rate', 'Pupil Teacher Ratio')
titles =c('Frequency plot of Crime Rate', 'Frequency plot of Tax Rate', 'Frequency Plot of Pupil:Teacher')


hist(Boston[sectors[1]],ylab='Frequency',xlab=as.character(xlabels[1]),main=as.character(titles[1]))
```

This produces the wrong image, where as you can see the titles and labels are wrong.
[Not expected behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0STm6.png)

I'm not observing any error messages, and I'm not entirely sure what to call this effect to google it correctly. I apologize if this has been answered before and would appreciate any and all help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Running your second set of code, changing `Boston[sectors[1]]` to `Boston[,sectors[1]]`,seems to produce the same plot for me

Comment: This seem to work for me : `hist(Boston[[sectors[1]]],ylab='Frequency',xlab= xlabels[1],main= titles[1])`

Comment: Thanks @Snel23 and Ronak Shah, both those answer work. I'm confused as to why I need to call the subindex for the right behaviour. Would you be able to explain that?

Comment: The code failed without adding it, so my guess is that the plot you were seeing was a previous plot that you had made, but thought that the code you put in produced it, but instead your code failed and produced nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the difference:

```
str(Boston[sectors[1]])
'data.frame':   506 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ crim: num  0.00632 0.02731 0.02729 0.03237 0.06905 ...
str(Boston[, sectors[1]])
# num [1:506] 0.00632 0.02731 0.02729 0.03237 0.06905 ...
str(Boston[[sectors[1]]])
# num [1:506] 0.00632 0.02731 0.02729 0.03237 0.06905 ...
```

A data frame is a special kind of list so it can get confusing. The first example extracts the first element of the list (which here is also a column) and returns it as a list (a data frame). You should get an error message because the hist function does not take a list/data frame but a vector. The second uses the matrix/data frame way of extracting a column so you get a numeric vector. The third example treats Boston as a list and extracts just the first element and returns it without wrapping it in a list. The `?Extract` manual page talks about this but it can take multiple readings to begin to figure it out. Also using `str()` can help you figure out what you are getting.

Also, your vectors are character so you do not need `as.character()`:

```
i <- 3
hist(Boston[, sectors[i]], ylab='Frequency', xlab=xlabels[i], main=titles[i])
```